# How to list every value between cells throughout entire columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a loop that prints every value between two cells in a row into a single column. I would also like it to skip/ignore non integer values.

For example: Cell A5 contains 5673 and Cell B5 contains 5677. Therefore the macro would output 5673, 5674, 5675, 5676, and 5677.

I have found some useful examples for looping through each row and printing each value, but have not been able to combine the two.

To print each value between the two numbers:

```
[D1] = [A1].Value
ato = [B1].Value
[D1].DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1, Stop:=ato
```

To loop through every row:

```
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 1 To LR
   Cells(j, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value = ***Every cell value between Cells(j, 1) and Cells(j, 2)***
Next j
```

Before:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Hn4aS2h.png]

Desired after:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/LYgmuZz.png]

Comment: Where does 5674 come from? Have you tried any code?

Comment: Looks like you want a loop to cycle through your array plus a nested loop inside an if statement where `if cell <> cells.offset(,1) then` loop between from start to finish; append to the last row in the column+1.  Include `IsNumber()`.  Take a stab with that and update your post with your new info.

Comment: @SJR I just updated my post to hopefully add some clarification. I want each value between the numbers in adjacent columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can use `SpecialCells` to pick out the numerical cells, and `Fill` to produce the intervening sequences.

```
Sub x()

Dim rA As Range, rCell As Range

For Each rA In Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Areas
    For Each rCell In rA
        Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Value = rCell.Value
        Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Step:=1, Stop:=rCell.Offset(, 1), Trend:=False
    Next rCell
Next rA

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I will be honest that I don't understand how the inner loop is working but I will try to dissect and understand. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure. The first area covers all the contiguous numbers in column A, i.e. A1:A2 so you then need to loop through each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you will always have these 2 columns, then you may use this code

```
for j = 1 to 2:for i = 1 to cells(rows.count,j).end(xlup).row
if isnumeric(cells(i,j)) then cells(rows.count,4).end(xlup).offset(1,0) = cells(i,j)
next:next
```

bear in mind that it will post everysingle number, if you need to delete duplicates, you may do it using range.removeduplicate

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the range cell by cell; test for `IsNumeric` and `Duplicate values`. Note: this is just a test code, you should always add workbook and worksheet references

```
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To 2
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, j)) And Cells(i, j).Offset(, 1).Value <> Cells(i, j).Value Then
            If IsEmpty(Cells(1, 4).Value) Then
                Cells(1, 4) = Cells(i, j)
            Else: Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Cells(i, j)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```